# How to create multiple boxes with onclick event

Tags: javascript

Upon `onclick`, I need to generate multiple boxes with unique ids and random positions.

Here is my [effort so far](http://jsfiddle.net/christopherpl/gnVj6/):

```
<h1>The Amazing Box App</h1>
<form id="data">
<ol>
<li>Pick a name for your Amazing Box: <br>
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="name" size="20" placeholder="My Amazing Box ..">
</li>
<li>Pick a color for your Amazing Box: <br>
<select id="color">
<option value="">Pick a color</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
<option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="indigo">Indigo</option>
<option value="violet">Violet</option>
</select>
</li>
<li>How many Amazing Boxes do you want to create?<br>
<input type="radio" id="five" name="amount" value="5">
<label for="five">5</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="ten" name="amount" value="10">
<label for="ten">10</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="fifteen" name="amount" value="15">
<label for="fifteen">15</label><br>
</li>
</ol>
<p>
<input type="button" id="generateButton" value="Generate My Amazing Boxes">
<input type="button" id="clearButton" value="Clear My Amazing Boxes">
</p>
</form>
<div id="scene">
</div>
```

I am looking for a javascript only solution.

Comment: What have you tried? I mean, it's your homework, you have to learn something with it.

Comment: This won´t work on stackoverflow!

Comment: @Christopher , what you need , on click you should be able to generate  3 boxes that you just numbered and all of them must have unique ids and position ?

Comment: Here is my effort so far: http://jsfiddle.net/christopherpl/gnVj6/

Comment: If a user picks the button with number 5, then 5 boxes of the chosen color must be generated, each with unique ids and positioning. If he wants to add more boxes, then he can easily go ahead and the previously generated boxes aren't erased.

Comment: Can anyone who loves javascript give a hand? Here is my javascript ...http://jsfiddle.net/christopherpl/gnVj6/

Answer (score 0):

To generate, you need to use the div "scene" or any other empty div tag you wish to use.

The functions need to be similar to the following:

```
function generateboxes(num, color) {
    clearboxes(); //first clear them
    for (var i=0; i<num; i++) {
        var top = Math.floor(Math.random()*300); //300 is the max vertical offset
        var left = Math.floor(Math.random()*200); //200 is the max horizontal offset
        var boxstyle = "position:absolute; top:"+top+"px; left:"+left+"px; background-color:"+color+";"; //Definition of box styles (you must set width and height for them to be visible)
        document.getElementById('scene').innerHTML += "<div style=\""+boxstyle+"\"></div>"; //Add one more box to the group
    }

function clearboxes() {
    document.getElementById('scene').innerHTML = ""; //By resetting the HTML of the div, we remove the boxes.
}
```

Also, don't forget about **function parameters** - and **you need to read the comments for visible boxes**.

Comment: Hi Scott. I am going to edit my code and let you know how it works out. Thank you for your time.